# Detect iOS network permission of my app

Tags: ios, networking, permissions

App needs permission of network to access network since from iOS 10.
How can I programmatically check if my app is set to "Off" or "WLAN" or "WLAN & Celluar Data"?

[Screenshot of "Allow App TO USE DATA"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arhYU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using Reachability.

```
Reachability *netReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[netReachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus networkStatus = [netReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(networkStatus == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet connection.
}
else if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //connected with WiFi network.
}
else if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //connected with 3G network.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sachin, but I don't think Reachability is useful for this. <BR> For example, If the user turn off both Wifi and Celluar, but set my app to allow access "WLAN & Celluar Data", the result would be NotReachable.

Comment: You can't tell if your app has been specifically denied network access, only that the network is or isn't reachable; This could be because your app has been denied network access or because there is no network